# problem with chromium: cannot open display:: 0.0

Tags: raspbian, ssh, display

I have a screen for raspberry pi
(this one: http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display)
to install the drivers for the screen I put (as said in the document below):

```
sudo rm -rf LCD-show
git clone https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git
chmod -R 755 LCD-show
cd LCD-show /
sudo ./LCD35-show
```

I installed chrominum thanks to this tutorial: [https://translate.google.fr/?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&text=https%3A%2F%2Fprojetsdiy.fr%2Fouvrir-page-html-demarrage-de-raspberry-pi-os-chromium-browser-plein-ecran-mode-kiosk-domoticz-jeedom-homeassistant%2F%23%3A~%3Atext%3DVous%2520pouvez%252C%2520bien%2520s%25C3%25BBr%252C%2520appuyer%2Clancera%2520automatiquement%2520en%2520plein%2520%25C3%25A9cran.&op=translate](https://translate.google.fr/?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&text=https%3A%2F%2Fprojetsdiy.fr%2Fouvrir-page-html-demarrage-de-raspberry-pi-os-chromium-browser-plein-ecran-mode-kiosk-domoticz-jeedom-homeassistant%2F%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3DVous%2520pouvez%252C%2520bien%2520s%25C3%25BBr%252C%2520appuyer%2Clancera%2520automatiquement%2520en%2520plein%2520%25C3%25A9cran.&op=translate)
(click on the google translate link)

but when I run the command:
/ usr / bin / chromium-browser --kiosk https://www.clockfaceonline.co.uk/clocks/digital/

it gives me: `(chromium-browser: 1304): Gtk-WARNING **: 09: 56: 42.152: cannot open display:: 0.0`

and the command `echo $ DISPLAY`
give me an empty line

Comment: The error message is trying to say that the process is not running in a session which is attached to a GUI. There is no way for it to create a window because it does not have access to your monitor (if X11 is even running).

Comment: Are you logged in locally (i.e. using VNC) or are you using SSH?

Comment: I assume you're `ssh`ing into the Pi. Did you include the `-X` flag in the `ssh` command?

Comment: I am connecting in ssh,
and what did you mean in Did you include the -X flag in the ssh command? - I did not confirm.

Comment: oh yes, ok on which command are you talking about?
the one to connect in ssh, the command for chromium, ........?